# Docker registry removing images vs removing tags

Tags: docker

Hi I got private docker registry and I want do delete specific images from it. I can check those images by

```
curl -Ss https://registry_url/v2/<repository_name>/tags/list
```

I don't know how to delete those images or tags. I mean If i correct I can delete tag only by

```
curl -X DELETE https://registry_url/v2/repositories/<repository_name>/tags/<some_tag>
```

But Im wondering if that will delete only tag or image that is related to that tag?